# How can i test Solr SearchComponent - JUnit Tests

Tags: java

I need to write a unit test for solr SearchComponent (SearchComponent.process ()).
How could I do that? Can I use SolrTestCaseJ4 or another way?
I am currently using SolrTestCaseJ4...

I am currently using SolrTestCaseJ4...

```
public class SearchComponentTest extends SolrTestCaseJ4 {
     @BeforeClass
     public static void beforeClass() throws Exception {
         initCore("collection1/conf/solrconfig.xml", "collection1/conf/schema.xml", "src/test/resources/");
     }

     @Test
     public void testPrepare() throws IOException {
         MySearchComponent component = new MySearchComponent();
         List<SearchComponent> components = new ArrayList<>();
         components.add(component);
         SolrQueryRequest req;
         ResponseBuilder rb;
         req = req("q", "*:*");
         rb = new ResponseBuilder(req, new SolrQueryResponse(), components);
         component.process(rb);
     }
}
```

and my SearchComponent:

```
public class MySearchComponent extends SearchComponent {
     public void process(ResponseBuilder rb) throws IOException {
      ....
        SolrQueryRequest req = rb.req;
        SolrQueryResponse rsp = rb.rsp;
        SolrParams params = rb.req.getParams();

        SchemaField keyField = rb.req.getCore().getLatestSchema().getUniqueKeyField();
        String core = rb.req.getCore().getName();

        SolrIndexSearcher searcher = req.getSearcher();
        QueryCommand cmd = rb.createQueryCommand();
        QueryResult result = new QueryResult();

        searcher.search(result, cmd);
        rb.setResult(result);

        BasicResultContext ctx = new BasicResultContext(rb, rb.getResults().docList);
        rsp.add("response", ctx);
        ...
     }
...
}
```

But i have NullPointerException on this line:
QueryCommand cmd = rb.createQueryCommand();

Thank you for your help!